# Application Load Balancer bypass SSL Termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an nginx that is configured for SSL Termination and work as expected for my application.
For Disaster Recovery purposes I want to set up an AWS Application Load Balancer in fron of my HTTPS NGINX. The ALB will be exposed with a Network LoadBalancer that will do the region switch.
The issue is that if I call my application, the AWS Application Load Balancer it's doing the SSL Termination and the certificates are not reaching NGINX:

```
400 No required SSL certificate was sent
400 Bad request
```

Since I would like to keep my SSL termination at the NGINX level, can I configure the AWS Application LoadBalancer Listener to forward the certificates for the nginx aslo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALBs are layer 7 load balancers that only support HTTP/HTTPS listeners. SSL passthrough has to happen before layer 7 actions so it's not possible to configure ALBs for SSL passthrough. However you should be able to do this with a network load balancer, using TCP listeners.

This AWS blog outlines a similar setup, but for ECS - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/maintaining-transport-layer-security-all-the-way-to-your-container-using-the-network-load-balancer-with-amazon-ecs/